# Photoshop: Transform or Scale layer via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, shortcuts, scale

I am looking for a way to scale/transform a Photoshop layer using the keyboard only. Similar to the way this is handled in InDesign would be ideal, with a dedicated keyboard shortcut I can assign (such as Command + , and Command + . in InDesign for Mac, if I recall the shortcut correctly).

One possible workaround solution to this would be to be able to highlight the first Scale field in the Options Bar (or any field in the Options Bar, actually) and just tab over to the Scale fields. But I've not been able to figure out a way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to make this happen using Actions, via [this post over on the Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2288134):

1. start recording a new Action
2. invoke the Transform command (Edit > Free Transform)
3. Enter a transformation percentage in the Width and Height boxes in the Options Bar, such as 110% to enlarge the layer by 10%
4. Hit return to accept the transformation
5. Stop recording the Action
6. Assign the action a keyboard shortcut (such as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>) via the Actions Options menu item in the Actions panel fly-out menu

Repeat this to scale down, using 90% in the percentage fields, and a similar keyboard shortcut.